Factoring the Z-transform of an autocorrelation into $F(z)F^*(1/z)$
I am working through Andreas Molisch's "Wireless Communications: From Fundamentals to Beyond 5G" (third edition), and am currently stuck on chapter 14, where it describes a noise-whitening filter to be used in an equalizer.
The discrete autocorrelation of the combined channel and basis-pulse impulse response is supposed to be calculated, and from there, the z-transform of the autocorrelation is to be factored into a product of polynomials $\Xi(z) = F(z)\overline{F(z^{-1})}$.
I do not know how to do that, generally speaking, nor do I know how to show that such a factorization is even possible for the z-transform of an autocorrelation. The closest I get is recognizing that for some general discrete signal $x$, $Z\{\phi_{xx}\} = X(z) \overline{X(\overline{z}^{-1})}$, which is so very close to the required factorization, but the stray conjugation in the inside of the second part ruins it.
So is the textbook incorrect, or is it also possible to factor the z-transform of an autocorrelation into $F(z)\overline{F(z^{-1})}$? If so, how?

If $F^*(1/z)$ is supposed to denote $[F(1/z)]^*$, then the book would be wrong. Note that
$$\big[F(1/z)\big]^*=\left[\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f[n]z^n\right]^*=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f^*[n](z^*)^n$$
is not a valid $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, because as such it must be a function of $z$, not of $z^*$.
The correct expression is
\begin{align*}
F^*\left(1/z^*\right) &= \left[\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f[n](z^*)^n\right]^*\\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f^*[n]z^n\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f^*[-n]z^{-n}\\
&= \mathcal{Z}\big\{f^*[-n]\big\}
\end{align*}
which is a valid $\mathcal{Z}$-transform.
It could be that by the notation $F^*(1/z)$, Molisch means
$$F^*(1/z)\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f^*[n]z^n$$
but in that case this should be clarified somewhere in the book.

I think your first intuition is correct, and that it's simply a typographical error for the correct expression.
